# How to get cell from UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Why does this code return a cell?

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

But when I am trying to get cell with 
`[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]]`
it does not return anything. Does anybody know how it is possible?

Comment: This code reuses cells that have already been created.  Did you create the cell in the first place?

Comment: Yes, of course. I just put the second code instead of first to test.

Comment: [tableView numberofRowsInSection:0] returns 7.

Comment: Where are you trying to use the get cell code? Provide more code to understand the context you are working on. Thanks.

Comment: You need to show more code, specifically cellForRowAtIndexPath, and maybe the context of your problem (i.e. what your trying to accomplish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **Return Value**
>
> An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

So if that cell is not currently visible then it will return `nil`. So, is it visible?

Other than that - check that you are actually creating cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` as you haven't specifically shown that you are.

Comment: Great!!! Thanks a lot for your answer. I did not know about it. I was spending so much time to figure it out :(